# Translation/transliteration question - "I never know what to say in these moments".

Tags: перевод, произношение, транслитерация

I came across this line in a [movie scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJKUpQwnORk) (at about 20 seconds in the video).

> "I never know what to say in these moments"

I looked up the translation in google translate -

And the translation was this -

> Я никогда не знаю, что сказать в эти моменты
>
> "YA nikogda ne znayu, chto skazat' v eti momenty"

But this sounds different from what the actor actually says. So what does he really say and how is it transliterated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

я никогда не знаю что говорить в такие моменты

Comment: That doesn't sound like what he said.

Comment: @CodeBlue, right, I didn't understand your question at first

Comment: @CodeBlue, but Aksakal is absolutely right, he wrote exactly what the actor says. The transliteration: "Ya nikogda ne znayu, chto govorit' v takiye momenty."

Comment: My first translation wasn't right, I didn't listen to actual video initially

Answer (score 0):

A couple of variations for you:

- В такие моменты, я теряю дар речи.
- В таких случаях, я обычно не знаю, что сказать.

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос о том что говорит актер, а не о том как это сказать правильно или красиво.

Answer (score 0):

According to the context in the clip, the translation should have been "I never know what to say at times like this." We don't use "moment" in English the same way they use it in Russian.